# How to get ALL of a user's Home Feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, feed

Tweetdeck is able to get every single status update or wall posting on the user's 'Home' page.  However, if I go to 'me/home,' I only get a subset of all the 'Home' page items.  I'm assuming this is the case because the user's friends disable apps from retrieving their data.

So, why does Tweetdeck fetch more posts than I do?  Is it a 'backdoor' or are they just using different code?

Comment: My guess is that tweetdeck has partnered with Facebook and is using a different API then we thirdparty developers have access (without entering into a partnership with facebook).

Answer (score 0):

I I assume your using Facebook C# SDK. If so, there a special permission you have to request to read the user’s stream.

I believe the permission is called **read_stream**. As opposed to **publish_stream** which posts to the user’s wall.

read_stream returns an array of Post objects containing (up to) the last 25 posts.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Provides access to all the posts in the user's News Feed and enables your application to perform searches against the user's News Feed.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/